# When i press hamburger icon in my React Native app the drawer opens only from the last screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using "@react-navigation" and I've created three screens, when I touch the hamburger icon the drawer menu only opens from the last screen, not from the others.

Any help on this?

Comment: Any code to show?

Comment: @Konstantin https://js.do/code/556537 here